# SVG/JavaScript pie chart with outside labels constrained by container width

Tags: javascript, svg, pie-chart

All examples of pie charts (with outside labels and lines) use labels positioned around the circle (diagram A below). The problem is that a container where my pie chart should be located has a width constrain equal to the width of the pie chart.

1) Is it possible to position the labels like on diagram B below? 
2) Is there any other solution addressing my problem?

NB! The labels cannot be placed inside the circle. I am happy to use any JavaScript library to achieve the required result.

[image]

Comment: Just a side comment, that certainly would not work well if there where many small slices on the 45 degree angle. You would also need to control that.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to http://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/HdwTH/ and do a view source in the pie chart area (please give credit to this author).  Paste the source into your IDE.

Make these modifications:

```
// Store our chart dimensions
    cDim = {
        height: 300, //500
        width: 300,//500
        innerRadius: 50,
        outerRadius: 150,
        labelRadius: 150 //175
    }
```

This uses the d3.js library

Comment: This implementation works exactly like on diagram A (i.e. the labels are not constrained, and positioned around the circle).